# SailsJS custom config files

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sails.js

I am aware I can create a custom file inside the config directory and reference the variables from within that

```
module.exports.myconfig = {
    foo: 'bar'
}

sails.config.myconfig.foo
```

But I need to write to these variables too and have them saved. In previous projects I have done this with **JSON** config files and used **PHP** to write to them.

Is there any way of doing this with Sails or should I just create some **JSON** files to pull and push my config vars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mechanism built in to Sails for persisting configuration variables.  However, in [the latest build of Sails](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails) there is a `lower` event you can listen for which indicates that Sails is exiting.  You could catch this and persist your data then.  For example, in your `/config/bootstrap.js`, something like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
module.exports = function(cb) {

   sails.on('lower', function persistConfig() {

      fs.writeFileSync(sails.appPath+'/config/myConfig.js', 
                       'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(sails.config.myconfig));

   });

   // ... other bootstrap stuff ...
   return cb();

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily need to do this on exit but good to know that event exists. I did think about string concatenation but wondered if there was a better way.